# How to convert a hex encoded UTF-8 string to a regular string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains a hexadecimal encoding of a UTF-8 string.

```
"666f6f6c 6973686e 6573732c 20697420 77617320 74686520 65706f63 68206f66 2062656c 6965662c 20697420 77617320 74686520 65706f63 68206f66 20696e63 72656475 6c697479 2c206974 20776173 20746865 20736561 736f6e20 6f66204c 69676874 2c206974 20776173 20746865 2073656"
```

I need to convert it back to a regular string. How can I do it?

Comment: http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx?

Comment: I got to say, it could be very tricky in javascript. Do you want to do it in javascript or just do it for once?

Comment: Well, if 'hexadecimal' really means 'each pair of hexsymbols encodes a single character' (as apparently is the case with this particular string), it's actually quite easy.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I need that functionality in javascript.

Comment: @xiaoyi: I need to do it in javascript.

Comment: @raina77ow: utf8 can have 4bytes together making one character :-(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
var s = "666f6f6c 6973686e 6573732c 20697420 77617320 74686520 65706f63 68206f66 2062656c 6965662c 20697420 77617320 74686520 65706f63 68206f66 20696e63 72656475 6c697479 2c206974 20776173 20746865 20736561 736f6e20 6f66204c 69676874 2c206974 20776173 20746865 2073656";
var r = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[0-9a-f]{2}/g, '%$&'));
```

This solution actually handles UTF-8.

The idea is to put a `%` in front of every pair of hex digits (thus creating a URL encoded string), then letting [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) handle the details (in particular, it will correctly decode multi-byte UTF-8 characters).

Comment: will it handle the case where the original was encoded to 2 or more bytes ?

Comment: Yes, that's what "UTF-8" means.

Comment: If your hex data has no spaces, e.g. coming from PostgreSQL as a JSON value, all you need is the second replace - .replace(/[0-9a-f]{2}/g, '%$&')

Answer (score 2):

To properly handle UTF8 you may want to try this approach:

```
    function utf8ToHex(str) {
      return Array.from(str).map(c => 
        c.charCodeAt(0) < 128 ? c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) : 
        encodeURIComponent(c).replace(/\%/g,'').toLowerCase()
      ).join('');
    },
    function hexToUtf8: function(hex) {
      return decodeURIComponent('%' + hex.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('%'));
    }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lyquix/k2tjbrvq/

Answer (score 1):

Node only solution.
There's the `Buffer` class that can convert between data (e.g. utf bytes and utf8 strings.

```
Buffer.from(0x66, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x6c).toString(); // 'fool'
```

So for your space-deliminated string format of bytes, you would:

```
let s = '666f6f6c 6973686e 6573732c';

// [102, 111, 111, 108, 105, 115, 104, 110, 101, 115, 115, 44]
let bytes = [...s.matchAll(/[^ ]{1,2}/g)].map(a => parseInt(a[0], 16));

Buffer.from(bytes).toString(); // 'foolishness,'
```

Answer (score 1):

The new [TextDecoder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) provides a solution. Adapting [junvar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68668368/7941251):

```
let s = '666f6f6c 6973686e 6573732c';

// [102, 111, 111, 108, 105, 115, 104, 110, 101, 115, 115, 44]
let bytes = [...s.matchAll(/[0-9a-f]{2}/g)].map(a => parseInt(a[0], 16));

// TextDecoder defaults to UTF-8
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(bytes)));
```

Note that this solution works on both Node.js (v8.3.0+) and a browser ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/textencoder)) .

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
function HexToString(s) {
  var escaped = "";
  var hex = "";
  if(s.length%4 > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < (4 - (s.length % 4)); i++) {
      hex += "0";
    }
  }
  hex += s;
  for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 4) {
    escaped += "%u" + hex.charAt(i) + hex.charAt(i + 1) + hex.charAt(i + 2) + hex.charAt(i + 3);
  }
  return unescape(escaped).split(unescape("%00")).join("");
}
```

It's works for me.