# Unhexlify in Javascript doesn't work with accents

Tags: javascript, python, hex

Long story short, I'm sending an Excel file from Python to Javascript. To do so, I need to send it as a string (very dirty but this is a constraint on my side), and so, I "hexlify" (or use .hex(), any way to do it is ok as long as it works in the Javascript) my Excel file in Python and send it to the Javascript.

```
    with open(EXCEL_TEMPLATE_OUTPUTS, "rb") as f:
        encrypted_bytes = f.read()
    
    return encrypted_bytes.hex()
```

The difficulty now is to convert it back to an array of bytes in the Javascript, so that I can create a Blob. To do so, I'm using the function below:

```
var unhexlify = function(str) {
var bytes = [];
for (var i=0, l=str.length; i<l; i+=2) {
  bytes.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str.substr(i, 2), 16)));
}
return bytes;
```

It works quite well except for some characters. For example, "c8" is converted into "È" instead of "\xc8". So, the file I'm rebuilding is corrupted. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

EDIT: Here below is an example highlighting the problem:

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(parseInt("c8", 16)));
```

As you can see, it is sending "È" instead of "\xc8", while in Python:

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
unhexlify("c8")
# b'\xc8'
bytes.fromhex('c8')
# b'\xc8'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert a string containing utf8 hex codes to a javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865302/how-to-convert-a-string-containing-utf8-hex-codes-to-a-javascript-string)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt

Comment: Some characters take more than two bytes in Unicode

Comment: @Konrad Presumably, that should be `String.fromCodePoint`, no?

Comment: Also, it doesn't work properly because JS uses UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: @SuperStormer Unfortunately no, I already have had a look at this question...

Comment: @SuperStormer fromCodePoint gives the same output

Comment: Maybe the python part is wrong

Comment: @Konrad Unlhexify function works like a charm in Python. The problem is that I don't have the equivalent in Javascript. String.fromCharCode seems to send the wrong output for some characters.

Comment: I read the question again and I think I know what the problem is. `unhexify` takes a string and returns bytes. Strings in JavaScript are not meant to store raw bytes of data. I would consider using `ArrayBuffer` or something else depending on what you want to do with this data

Comment: I'll edit the question, but I'm actually building an array of bytes. I'll also add some details to reproduce the issue

Comment: So string is not a valid data type. You can use string but it won't work the same as python's binary

Comment: Ok but then, what can I use to make it work the way I want?

Comment: [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) or [Int32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int32Array). Notice that you don't use string in python either, you use [byte literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution that actually get rid of String.fromCharCode(). The idea here is to create a Uint8Array from the hex sent from Python:

```
var typedArray = new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {return parseInt(h, 16)}))
```

I can then create a blob based on this Uint8Array:

```
const blob = new Blob([typedArray], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
```

Thanks @Konrad. You guided me on the right path to find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

maybe the error is in the `str.padStart(2,'0')` code during encoding. or you can specify some hex you want to decode

```js
var hexlify = function(str){
   return [...str].map(e => 
       e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
         .padStart(2, '0') // a -> 0a
      ).join('')
}
var unhexlify = function(str) {
   return String.fromCharCode(...
     str.match(/.{1,2}/g) // ['68','65','6c','6c','6f']
     .map(e => parseInt(e, 16))
     )
}
console.log(hexlify('hello'), unhexlify('68656c6c6f')) // 68656c6c6f hello
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: looks like python has a different calculation if characters are more than `String.fromCharCode(127)` https://onlinegdb.com/nLInjsjIT

Comment: Indeed. But then, how to overcome this? I'm not able to find anything doing it...

Comment: The solution is to create a function with a manual data list in Python that fits in JavaScript. eg `{l:'6c',o:'6f',..}`